# Adding utility scripts to a create-react-app React / Typescript app

Tags: javascript, typescript, create-react-app

I have a Typescript single-page React app created using `create-react-app --typescript`. The source code is in `.ts` and `.tsx` files in `src/`.

Now I want to create some utility scripts to use in development. In this case, to download data from our production server and upload it to my local development server, but that's just an example. The scripts have dependencies that the app also has (like an API client library) and I want to *import from the App* for various constants and helper functions.

Is there a place in create-react-app's structure where I can put such scripts and have them work? I want to be able to call them with `npm run scriptname` and have them import from the App.

(on our Django backends I would make these into Django management commands, I'm looking for a way to make something similar)

Answer (score 5):

I create a folder in `src` called `scripts`.

It might look like

```
- scripts
  |- lint.ts
  |- deploy.ts
```

Then in my `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
  // ... add commands:
  "deploy:staging": "ts-node ./src/scripts/deploy.ts --staging",
  "deploy:production": "ts-node ./src/scripts/deploy.ts --production",
  "lint:check": "eslint ./src",
  "lint:format": "eslint ./src --fix"
}
```

Run like any other script: `npm run link:format`

Answer (score 0):

Create-React-App imposes very few restrictions on your project, even if you don't eject. You have the ability to add any custom scripts to package.json's `"scripts"` section so you can create custom npm/yarn commands for yourself.

I like to put my scripts in a `scripts` directory next to `src` as a reminder to myself that this code is not part of my react app (specifically, not part of the bundles that are created when I build for production).

For example, to add a command that populates your dev environment, you can write a nodeJS program that does it, and add the command to your package.json as follows:

```json
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    // ...
    "populatedev": "node scripts/populate-dev-environment"
  },
```

Or, if you prefer a bash script,

```json
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    // ...
    "populatedev": "./scripts/populateDev.sh"
  },
```

In either case you would run this command from your CLI as follows:

```sh
npm run populatedev

# or if you prefer yarn

yarn populatedev
```